# Weak learners for XGBoost with Tweedie distribution

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, tweedie-distribution

Could you please explain what are the standard weak learners for XGBoost 
when the **objective** parameter equals **reg:tweedie**? 
Are they  GLMs (with Tweedie distribution of dependent variable) on 
all possible subsets of the set of my predictors? Are GLMs with interactions of the form x_i*x_j also included?

Answer (score 3):

The standard base learners when selecting the use of `reg:tweedie` are tree-based models, i.e. `gbtree`. We can use a linear model as a base learner but it is not by default. When we set `reg:tweedie` we effectively a Tweedie distribution's negative log-likelihood as your objective function and we do not directly affect the base learner. (To be a bit more precise: we actually use the gradient and the hessian of Tweedie log-likelihood in the objective function specification; the negative log-likelihood of the Tweedie regression is used as the evaluation metric but the evaluation metric can be changed to something like `MAE` and still used `reg:tweedie` as our objective function. The code implementing these computations for the Tweedie objective can be found [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/daf77ca7b70b3d85666d3376c22bca33b8139f07/src/objective/regression_obj.cu).)

Finally, no, interactions between variables are not directly considered. If we think a particular interaction should be considered we should form it manually. If interaction effects occur, they are expected to be captured through the boosting procedure.

Comment: Thanks. So are we basically minimizing a certain loss function based on Tweedie log-likelihood?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.